# Mockito: Mocking different classes method in a specific class scope

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'd like to do this mocking with Mockito

**MyServiceClass**
(this isn't the actual code, just a fake example with a similar intent)

```
public String getClassObjects() {
    OtherClassObject otherclass = OtherClassObject.createOtherClassObject();
    String id = otherclass.getParentObject().getId();
    return id;
}
```

So essentially I want to mock **".getId()"** but only in the context of this class **"MyServiceClass"** if I call the same method of **"getId()"** in a different class I want to be able to mock a different return.

This will return "3" in every method call for the OtherClassObject

```
new MockUp<MyServiceClass>() {
        @Mock
        public String getId(){
            return "3";
        }
    };
```

Is there a way to isolate method calls for a class object within the scope of a specific class?

Comment: Why not to mock entire `getClassObjects` method?

Comment: Sorry my example isn't great, my intent is to test this method and one of its methods goes into another class that uses the same object and method (OtherClassObject.getId())

Answer (score 0):

Plain `Mockito` is unable to mock static calls, so you need `PowerMock` here. To achieve desired you should return different values from the mocked object like this

```
// from your example it's not clear the returned type from getParentObject method. 
// I'll call it ParentObj during this example. Replace with actual type.
ParentObj poOne = mock(ParentObj.class); 
when(poOne.getId()).thenReturn("3");

ParentObj poTwo = mock(ParentObj.class);
when(poTwo.getId()).thenReturn("10");

...

OtherClassObject otherClassObjectMock = mock(OtherClassObject.class);
// return all your stubbed instances in order
when(otherClassObjectMock.getParentObject()).thenReturn(poOne, poTwo); 

PowerMockito.mockStatic(OtherClassObject.class);
when(OtherClassObject.createOtherClassObject()).thenReturn(otherClassObjectMock);
```

Thus, you can customize your mocks per needs, specifying desired return value, or propagating call to actual (real) method.
Don't forget to use annotations `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(OtherClassObject.class)` on class level to activate the magic of `PowerMock`.

An alternative idea is to get rid of static call inside your `getClassObjects` method and pass factory using constructor, so you can easily mock it, setting mocked object only for single class.

Hope it helps!